# I have a design in Figma, how to use shapes/path to make it in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I saw couple of examples of Shapes/Paths in Xamarin, but couldn't get how to stretch my shape from Figma, for example to fill screen.

[image]

Having this design I exported this shape to svg, then I copy-pasted its path data to an element like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="80">
                    <Path Fill="Yellow"
                          HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                          Data="M1170 0H0V478L56.7107 534.711C75.4643 553.464 100.9 564 127.421 564L1042.58 564C1069.1 564 1094.54 553.464 1113.29 534.711L1170 478V0Z"
                    />
                    <Image Source="tgameicon" />
                    <Label Text="Gamer's calendar" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                </StackLayout>
```

I expect that HorizontalOptions="Fill" will fit this Path horizontally and Path proportionally will be scaled to fit, as I see - it is not correct, so my question - how to do it?
How to make an element with Path as Background that will be fit horizontally and scaled proportionally vertically. I expect that it has to be scaled proportionally as Path figure has some width/height aspect.

Comment: You didn't show a picture of what it looked like after you tested it, but if I had to guess, it's the StackLayout. If you want the purple shape to appear behind the image and label, you'll need to use a layout that allows that, such as a Grid, Absolute Layout, or Relative Layout

Answer (score 1):

Get your `Path` out of your `StackLayout` and overlap them both using a `Grid`:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="80" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Path Data="M1170 0H0V478L56.7107 534.711C75.4643 553.464 100.9 564 127.421 564L1042.58 564C1069.1 564 1094.54 553.464 1113.29 534.711L1170 478V0Z"
                  Fill="Yellow"/>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="tgameicon" />
                <Label FontAttributes="Bold"
                         FontSize="Large"
                         Text="Gamer's calendar"
                         TextColor="Red"/>
            </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think the path you provided won't render as the shape in the picture you attached